# How to show number of connected clients to a website running on nginx server?

Tags: nginx, client-server, client

I have a raspberry pi running an Nginx server. I want to write a small site that runs on this server that is capable of showing the number of connections currently active on the server. I know I can do this:

```
location /nginx_status {
    # Turn on stats
    stub_status on;
    access_log   off;
    # only allow access from 192.168.1.5 #
    allow 192.168.1.5;
    deny all;
}
```

Which works fine, but I was hoping to embed the active connections number into my site so that it will update in real time. Anyone know a simple way to do this? I can think of a few dirty "hack-ish" ways using the log files...but I would prefer a cleaner method.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Couldn't find a way to do exactly this, so I ended up using [Logstalgia](https://github.com/acaudwell/Logstalgia). You can tail a remote log using:

```
ssh user@example.com tail -f /var/log/apache2/access.log | logstalgia --sync
```